# How do I interpret the output of mce?

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, dmesg

My PC recently restarted on its own, and following that [abrt](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/abrt/about.html) notified me that there had been a likely hardware-related error. Checking out dmesg, I found the following lines from mce:

```
[    0.554142] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    0.554143] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 3: baa0000000040118
[    0.554145] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 MISC d012000100000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 300b000000000 
[    0.554148] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:870f10 TIME 1590567072 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8701013
```

How would I interpret this? I note that it reports the microcode version, which socket my CPU is in (0, since I only have one), and so forth, but does that mean that the CPU is at fault? I would appreciate some light on the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mcelog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mcelog) program can supply some explanations:

```
/usr/sbin/mcelog --ascii < error_text
```

I extracted the error text part:

```
Machine check events logged
CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 3: baa0000000040118
TSC 0 MISC d012000100000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 300b000000000 
PROCESSOR 2:870f10 TIME 1590567072 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8701013
```

Then I ran it on a Linux Mint VM, which gave me a very partial analysis,
where the important part was:

```
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
```

You would get more details by running the analysis on the computer where the error
happened.

My own opinion, based on your information, is that this is a RAM problem
on memory bank 3 address `baa0000000040118`.